# Is it possible to purchase/activate a Steam game that has been removed from the Store?

Tags: steam

Is it somehow possible to purchase or otherwise activate a game that has been removed from the Steam Store?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a third party to buy a key from and then activate it on steam. Please keep in mind during the purchase wherever you find the game you are looking for key make sure it can be activated on steam!

Comment: I can confirm: I bought Middle-earth: Shadow of War Gold Edition from a third party (with box and all) in November 2018. The Gold edition itself isn't available anymore on steam, though the game is.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of woof is correct, but there is another way. The original 'The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim' can't be found anymore by searching if you search in steam. If you search for Skyrim, you get the newer version. You can still visit [the page](https://store.steampowered.com/app/72850/) through your browser though if you know the link.

However, someone who has the original game still in their library can still navigate to the store page and buy the game as a gift (I tested untill I had to purchase).

Comment: That's a pretty cool loophole - so if you can find someone who already owns your target game, you can ask them to buy it for you as a gift (and pay them back)?

Comment: Small disclaimer: Note that I never really bought the game for someone else. But I was able to put it in my basket and select a friend to gift it to.

Comment: Is it also possible to just search the store for the steam app ID of the game?  To me being able to access the page implies that it's still at the same spot, just not indexed for searching.

Comment: @JMac You can still use your browser to go directly to the page. For example: this is the link for Skyrim: https://store.steampowered.com/app/72850/. Maybe I did not word it correctly, I'll try to rephrase.

Comment: Yeah that line about knowing the link clears up what I was wondering about.  It's really just knowing the number linked to the game.